# Is it advisable to create a repository for the Android SDK for use on build server

Tags: android, continuous-integration, bamboo

We are using Bamboo to build our Android projects.  The problem is that the server does not have the latest Android sdk installed.  The server also has no internet access.  Is it a bad idea to create a source control repository with the SDK that we can check out as part of the build?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a separate repository where you are storing all Android SDK related files. Then when some of the builds fail or new SDK come, just push them to repository. You should then configure triggers on Bamboo that autopull repository content to your offline server.